# Concatenate two fields from two classes in select list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, concatenation

I need to concatenate two fields from 2 different classes in a selectList.  So I created a non-mapped field in the class that I want to be able to pull from based on a virtual field (pointing at the other table).  However, when I try to run it, I am getting a weird error.

Here is my class code:

```
  [Display(Name = "Problem")]
  [ForeignKey("Problem")]
  [Required]
  public Guid ProblemId { get; set; }

  public virtual Problem Problem { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Category")]
  [NotMapped]
  public string FullCategory
  {
       get
       {
            return "(" + this.Problem.ProblemName.ToString() + ") " + CategoryName;
       }
   }
```

and then the Select list:

```
ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories.Where(c => c.Status == 1).OrderBy(c => c.Problem.ProblemName), "CategoryId", "FullCategory");
```

and it crashes on this line:

```
return "(" + this.Problem.ProblemName.ToString() + ") " + CategoryName;
```

with this error:

> {"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command
>   which must be closed first."}

However, if I change the code to this:

```
return "(" + Status + ") " + CategoryName;
```

then it works but of course it is not the result that I am looking for.  Status is another field in this class.

I also tried it without the .ToString() and I tried it with .First() - none of them worked

Comment: before return are you upto any data connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error typically occurs when you have two data readers open at the same time on a data connection.  You can try enabling multiple active result sets on your connection string (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=myDataSource;" + 
    "Initial Catalog=myCatalog;Integrated Security=mySecurity;" +
    "MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try enumerating the query.

```
ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(
     db.Categories
       .Include("Problem") // eager load
       .Where(c => c.Status == 1)
       .OrderBy(c => c.Problem.ProblemName)
       .ToList(), // enumerate 
     "CategoryId", 
     "FullCategory");
```